# Why Plugin Not Working In my html to wordpress convert theme?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Plugin Not Working In my html to wordpress convert theme, Some plugin work prefectly like SEO yoast, contact form7 but when i install gallery plugin is not working properly

Comment: other plugins are working fine means, there is a problem in gallery plugin

Answer (score 1):

For your plugins to work with the theme you must add wp_head() and wp_footer() in your custom wordpress theme.

You can add wp_head() before closing the  tag and wp_footer() before closing the  tag.

You can also watch this video to completely understand the HTML to Wordpress Conversion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcdB084noRo

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem description is incomplete i can guess that you have missed one or two of  wp_head() and wp_footer() functions.

wp_head() should be used before  tag in the header.php.

wp_footer() should be used before  tag in the footer.php.

Additionally you have to print post contents through get_the_content() or the_content() functions. Not directly echo $post->post_content.